# How to transform a maximizing objective function which contains a max operator to a standard LP form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

My Optimization objective function looks like this:

$\max\quad(c_1 x_1 + c_2 \max\{x_2, x_3, x_4\})$

all variables, $x_i$ are binary variables. There are also some linear constraints such as $a_ix_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 < 3$. I am asking is there any method which could help to transform this objective function to a standard form (which means there is no max-max).

I know there is a method which uses big-M coefficient. I need to transform the objective function to this one:

$\max\quad(c_1 x_1 + c_2x_5)$

while add 4 other constraints:

$$
x_5 \leq x_2 + x_6M\\
x_5 \leq x_3 + x_7M\\
x_5 \leq x_4 + x_8M\\
x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 2
$$

$M$ is a big enough coefficient and $x_6, x_7, x_8$ are binary. I was wondering whether my transformation is correct. Since $x_i$ are all binary, is there any simpler method? If any one of $x_2, x_3, x_4$ is 1, the objective function could turn to $c_1x_1 + c_2$

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this: introduce a new binary decision variable $z \in \{0,1\}$ and write the objective as:
$$ \min -c_1x_1 - c_2z$$
subject to:
$$ z\ge x_2$$
$$ z \ge x_3 $$
$$ z \ge x_4 $$

plus all remaining original constraints.

In short, we are simply modeling $ z = \max\{x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and changing the problem type to  min-max.

Comment: I have considered your idea before. it is not appropriate in this setting because it will only give correct answer with objective function which looks like $\min c_1x_1 + c_2 \max\{x_3, x_4, x5\}$

Comment: You can convert from $\max$ to $\min$ by multiplying by $-1$, so I don't see what the problem is. Change your goal to say $\min -c_1x_1 - c_2z$.

Comment: Oh,yeah. That's one way to do that. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am afraid If i transform like that. It turns to $\min−c_1x_1−c_2\min\{x_3, x_4, x_5\}$. Still, it is not the max-min or min-max form

Comment: It should not because the constraints $z \ge ...$ model the max piece, and that remains unchanged. You're only changing the cost coefficients.

Comment: This is the right start, however, $z$ should not be restricted to be a binary variable. In particular, this is no longer a linear program (it's an integer program) and it is possible that with this approach the problem no ponger has feasible solutions.

Comment: It wasn't a linear program to begin with, since he wanted all his $x_i$ to be binary. But your point about $z$ is valid; even though he needs a max over three binary variables, which has to be binary, relaxing it reduces the size of the b&b tree.

Comment: You confused him by changing it to $min$. You could just as easily have done $max \ c_1 x_1 + c_2 z$ with the constraints being $x_i \leq z$ for $i = 2,3,4$. They key being that the max term in the objective function will naturally "push" z to be the right value.

Comment: @wonko Notice in the comments thread where he mentions he wants a min-max form;I have changed my answer in light of that comment. Originally I wrote it with the goal unchanged.

Comment: He said its not in the min-max form, not that he wants it in the min-max form. One could argue that what he was actually saying was that your formulation was good precisely because it was not in the min-max form. Not sure how any of that is relevant though. Either way your answer was correct :). Probably time to close this thread.